# button is not clickable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor

i need to click a button in a sub-header on clicking it will move to next new page, but here my button is not clickable while test is running

```
var quotationList,
        leadListElems,
        createQuotationButton,
        quotationCreateCount,
        leadNameTittle,
        ionList;

        beforeEach(function() {
            leadListElems           = element.all(by.css('ion-item.item.item-stable'));
            quotationList           = element(by.css('.list'));
            createQuotationButton   = element.all(by.css('.button .button-clear'));
            quotationCreateCount    = element.all(by.css('.title .ng-binding .title-left'));
            leadNameTittle          = element(by.css('.title .nav-bar-title .ng-binding'));
            ionList                 = element(by.css('.scroll-content .ionic-scroll  .has-subheader'));
        });

    it('should create a new Quotation',function(){
        leadListElems.get(5).click().then(function(){
            expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/lead/details/5');
            browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
                createQuotationButton.click().then(function(){
                    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/details/5/quotation/create/');
                    expect(leadNameTittle.getAttribute('value')).toContain('1');
                    expect(ionList.getAttribute('value')).toContain('');    
                    browser.sleep(5000);
                browser.navigate().back();
                });
            });
        });
```

createQuotationButton is not clickable while test is running
my html for that button looks like this

```
<a class="button button-clear" ng-show="!userService.isOffline" style="width: 20px; float: right; margin-bottom: -10px" ng-click="onQuotCreate()">
            <i class="icon ion-plus-circled" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
        </a>
```

this is my header of that page
2
i need to click that button and move to next page my issue is to make that button clickable

Comment: How is it not clickable? Is it visible? Can you click it but nothing happens? Do you get any exception in the JavaScript console window? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: the button should be clicked and it should move on to this page and look at its header to match a value but this process stops at button click and sets err "Expected '/lead/details/5/' to match '/details/5/quotation/create/'."
 "NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".title .nav-bar-title .ng-binding")"

Comment: it is visible i could click it manually but i could not click it by test case program

Comment: i simply added an "id" to it now it is clickable and its moving to next page

Comment: You can probably post that as an answer and later accept it. Future visitors will look for an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

i simply added an "id" to it now it is clickable and its moving to next page

```
<a class="button button-clear" id="myId" ng-show="!userService.isOffline" style="width: 20px; float: right; margin-bottom: -10px" ng-click="onQuotCreate()">
            <i class="icon ion-plus-circled" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>
        </a>



 var quotationList,
            leadListElems,
            createQuotationButton,
            quotationCreateCount,
            leadNameTittle,
            ionList;

            beforeEach(function() {
                leadListElems           = element.all(by.css('ion-item.item.item-stable'));
                quotationList           = element(by.css('.list'));
                createQuotationButton   = element(by.id('myId'));
                quotationCreateCount    = element.all(by.css('.title .ng-binding .title-left'));
                leadNameTittle          = element(by.css('.title .nav-bar-title .ng-binding'));
                ionList                 = element(by.css('.scroll-content .ionic-scroll  .has-subheader'));
            });

        it('should create a new Quotation',function(){
            leadListElems.get(5).click().then(function(){
                expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/lead/details/5');
                browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
                    createQuotationButton.click().then(function(){
                        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/details/5/quotation/create/');
                        expect(leadNameTittle.getAttribute('value')).toContain('1');
                        expect(ionList.getAttribute('value')).toContain('');    
                        browser.sleep(5000);
                    browser.navigate().back();
                    });
                });
            });
```